# how to keep "plugins/contact-form-7/includes/js/scripts.js" in the wordpress header while remove the unused js by "wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );"?

Tags: wordpress

to speed up my website, i tired to  remove the  "wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js" and "js/jquery/jquery.js" by below code：

```
 function my_jquery_enqueue() {
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_jquery_enqueue' );
```

after this, "wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js" and "js/jquery/jquery.js"  all removed, but

the Contact form 7 is not working well.

is there a method to remove only "wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js" and "js/jquery/jquery.js" but keep other js files?  Thank u

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately practically all wordpress plugins use jquery which is the basis of js in wordpress. If you remove jquery you will be disabling all plugins practically. So it is not advisable to do this. To keep plugins running without jquery you will have to re-program each plugin manually which will be a lot of work unnecessarily.

Comment: but i checked the official twenty-nineteen theme, it has no such 2 js files

Comment: These files come from the core of WordPress and not from the theme folder. By default Wp has several registered js files that you can use without having to install in your theme or plugin, check this link: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/

Comment: thanks for your help. let me explain my questions again, im customizing the my own theme based on twenty sixteen and i found out the "wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js" and "js/jquery/jquery.js"  affected my website speed, so i want to remove them from header. but failed, if they are necessary for wordpress theme, but why Twenty nineteeen theme do not have those 2 files in the wp_head(). So i just want to find a correct way remove them without affecting other normal plugins' js files. THank u

Comment: I understand, in case these themes they just aren't using. when any plugin requests js they will appear in the tbm header. otherwise several plugins will stop working. If in your theme they are appearing it is for two probable reasons 1 you are logged in so will call jquery. 2 you have a plugin that asks jquery for its proper functioning. Solution: If you want to stop using jquery you should give up some plugins. In your example would be to create your own forms without contactform. but plugins like woocommerce won't work either.

Comment: i just installed the cf7 plugin on twenty nineteen theme website , and the jquery.js and js-migrate.min.js show up again. So is it possible to load the 2 js file bymyself above wp_footer() ， so the plugins i installed can work properly and meanwhile reducing the load time for my website? Thank u . my current test website up.wpshare.org have such problem then i loaded the 2 js files bymyself but the confact form 7 not working well

Comment: Ideally, you use wordpress instead of your own, which happens that jquery from wp is an old version so new ones may not work properly. Yes you can load in footer but for that you must change all scripts for footer. And remember to load everything through the wp script registration function and not manually.

Comment: Your site is already extremely fast, is far above normal, I see no need to worry so much about jquery. I passed the test here and gave 94 out of 100 in performance score. About jquery I noticed that there are two jquery loading. What you can do is force async in the scripts. but this can lead to more problems. if you are using wordpress and want to use plugins it will hardly reach 100% but your site is already extremely fast with 0.8s loading / only 33s request I see no need to worry. congratulations for the super well done site;)

Comment: In this link you will see how to put in async https://wpshout.com/make-site-faster-async-deferred-javascript-introducing-script_loader_tag/. I hope my answers help you. Please could you give points and choose as valid answer if it helped you? it helps thank you very much and any questions just ask;)

Comment: thank you Kelvin, i treied to choose yours as valid answer but as my reputation score is less than 15, it failed. Later if i got 15 or more , i will come back to do that. Thank you very much